# How to change the API Name of the Utility bar of custom application

Tags: utility-bar

I have a custom application that i created, but I prefixed my custom application as XYZ_MYAPP, which was carried over to my utility bar setting and utility bar was named as XYZ_UTILITYBAR. now i want to change the prefxi to ABC. Changing the api name of the custom application is not changing the api name of the utility bar.
I was trying to find a way to change the api name of the utility bar

Comment: Can you provide an example screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

Utility bar is just a type of [FlexiPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) and is actually its own metadata even though, in the UI, Salesforce is basically creating/updating this for you through the Utility Items menu item when editing a custom application. The fact that Salesforce is doing this for you though means you're limited, in the UI, to what they provide. In this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_apps_lightning_utilities.htm&type=5), it mentions how the utility bar you created through the Lightning App Builder is linked to only that application (and you can only *add* or *edit* a utility bar through this). By edit, it's just the items that appear.

[image]

However, that same document mentions you can associate a Utility Bar deployed through API to multiple Apps.
[image]

That's your only option for existing apps (or, otherwise, you could've just created a new CustomApplication in the UI versus renaming an existing one). As it's referenced in CustomApplication by name, you'd need to update the CustomApplication after the fact to point to the new Utility Bar page.

So the following steps should help you achieve what you want if the name is that important:

1. Create a new FlexiPage with the desired name and copy the contents of the existing FlexiPage for the uitlitybar
2. Change `<masterLabel>` to be your new name as well without the underscores.
3. Deploy the page
4. Modify the `<utilityBar>newName_UtilityBar</utilityBar>` part of your CustomApplication to use the new name and deploy.